# wrapped functions of a dynamic library (ld -wrap) not used in the main program

Tags: c, linker, wrapper

I'd like to write a wrapper around pthread_create in a dynamic library.
I use ld -wrap to link my libwrap.so file.

When I link my application with "-Wl,--wrap,pthread_create -lwrap" it works fine, my function is called instead of the real one.

If I use only "-lwrap", only the functions of libwrap.so use my function, the ones in the application use the real one.

Is there any way to make the application use the wrapper functions of the dynamic library without linking the application with the "-Wl,--wrap,pthread_create" ?

Thanks,
Fred

Comment: The `--wrap pthread_create` argument is what the linker uses to know what function to actually wrap.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to make the application use the wrapper functions of the dynamic library without linking the application with the "-Wl,--wrap,pthread_create"

Yes, but wrapper functions are not the right way to go about it.

What you want is an interposer library. Read about library interposers [here](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/lib_interposers.html).

Comment: I already tried these ones. I was looking for another mechanism where the final user doesn't have to do anything when he links his binary with my library.

Comment: @Fred "mechanism where the final user doesn't have to do anything when he links his binary with my library" -- that's exactly what would happen if you put the inteposer *into* your library.